# How to do user specific deployment of web application?

Tags: web, architecture, load-balancing, web-deployment, system-design

I have a web application and I came across a scenario where I am about to release a new version of my application but I want that version to be available to only a specific set of users first?

For example my app has users (a, b, c, d, e, f g, h). I am releasing v2 of my app, these users do not need to know that I have released a new version of my app. Whenever users (a,b,c) try to access the application they should be redirected to v2 and whenever rest of the users try to access the application they should be redirected to v1.

How can this be achieved from the point of view of deployment and system design?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can do this is via feature flags. You deploy your application with the code for V2, but it will be available only for a specific set of users.
To do that, you need a feature flagging system.

[Launch Darkly](https://launchdarkly.com/) provides feature flagging as a service, I used it and I can't recommend it enough.

Just as a small preview on how it works, first you need to create a client object with a SDK (that you get from the platform):

```
LDClient ldClient = new LDClient("YOUR_SDK_KEY");
```

Then you need to build a `LDUser` object, which is just an abstraction for your user:

```
LDUser user = new LDUser("user@test.com");
```

Then you just use those objects to check the state of the feature flag. You configure the features on the platform, where you can see nice graphs and reports (when a feature was used or not, etc)

```
boolean showFeature = ldClient.boolVariation("your.feature.key", user, false);
if (showFeature) {
  // application code to show the feature (the V2 functionality, in your case)
}
else {
  // the code to run if the feature is off (the V1 functionality)
}
```

If you don't want to use this, you can build your own system, it depends on your use-cases if it really worth the effort or not (for simple scenarios, you can see this system as just a DB with an API in front of it)